# Mitigating vulnerabilities in audio libraries that cause physical damage

Tags: vulnerability, physical, protection, audio

As I pointed out [here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/issues/1331) in February 2022, people who gained brief direct or remote access to a machine can change the volume step or other things regarding sudden large changes to the sound volume (for example via xbindkeys or shortcuts).

This can directly cause lasting physical harm via ear damage to one or many people at once or damage speakers/headphones. I don't know why it's not considered a severe urgent vulnerability. Root access is not even required for the pactl command(s). However, nothing is being done about it at this repo which I think is very irresponsible.

**Which measures**, other than building in some mitigation in the pulseaudio code, could be done to prevent exploits of this from actually occurring in the wild (it seems unknown if they already have)?

I'm of course not asking about which measures could help prevent malicious actors from gaining access to machines or have pactl commands being run at certain times. This is from the standpoint of physical security (protection from harm to people's bodies) and also from the stance that more lines of defense would be better even *if* volunteer devs of that repo finally engage with this issue for a new package upgrade so that if one measure fails or is vulnerable, another one still holds.

Comment: Because people gaining direct access to any system means they can change settings on said system. The way people got access is the vulnerability, not the ability to change settings.

Comment: As I wrote, a) they don't need direct access and also harm mitigation is not irrelevant just because b) unauthorized access as well as c) authorized malicious access should be mitigated as well.

Comment: And suddenly I want to play some audio with very low recording volume. How do you plan on handling that? Or I use a headset with a different characteristic, so that what's unbearably loud in one headset is barely hearable in a different headset? How should PA handle this? The answer is simple: It *can't* be handled in software.

Comment: *"Which measures, other than building in some mitigation in the pulseaudio code, could be done to prevent exploits of this from actually occurring in the wild"* - limit the possible output of the attached hardware. *"However, nothing is being done about it at this repo which I think is very irresponsible."* - there is a comment in the post you link to which explains that its kind of impossible to set appropriate limits. To cite: *"I do not think that this problem can be solved in a general way because __PA does not have any information about how loud the hardware actually is__."*

Comment: @vidarlo Hence this question (there are some complications). SteffenUllrich You should also read my reply to that there: it is irrelevant in regards to limiting the pace of volume increases. In addition to that, this question is about measures in general, not only my proposed code change of limiting the pace of volume change.

Comment: I wrote an answer about the need to define a good threat model, but I deleted it because it was not a real answer, it should have been a comment. What I wanted to say is that without defining a threat model, it's hard to decide if this *weakness* is serious enough to be considered a vulnerability (it sounds like it's not). There could be software mitigations to this problem (and any other harmful volume-related problems), but they are probably not worth it (because most people don't care enough, risk is low, fixes would introduce unnecessary complexity and degrade user experience, etc.)

Comment: @reed It's certainly an issue that you point out but it doesn't change all that much. Considering impacts of UX is important (it doesn't have to decrease). I don't think the risk is low and in any case the potential direct harm is relatively high and the required effort to fix unknown. The main issue with the "threat model" objection is that a) it doesn't have to be your own machine (it could also be that of a person at a music venue for example where those affected include other people there) and b) many people have little IT skills or protections due to which limiting harm is still good.

Comment: @mYnDstrEAm, the threat model is useful to understand the threat exactly, because for example, we could talk about a malicious actor trying to suddenly increase the volume in a nightclub, or a simple incident where an user bumps into the volume by mistake and auto-destroys their own ears. If the problem is dangerous volume in general, then it might even be mitigated by running highest-volume tests before setting the volume. Like a beep at maximum perceived volume (by frequency/amplitude) to set the level, so that anything else afterwards is guaranteed to be comfortable.

Comment: Sure, this concerns both cases and further cases but (mitigating it) does not depend on how this could turn out to be dangerous. I think the problem is not loud volume in general but too fast increases in volume (and maybe increases in volume beyond a certain level without user confirmation). If it is increased only gradually above 100% volume, one can disconnect speakers, stop pressing a key, hold ears, put down the headphones, etc in at least most (maybe not all) cases. The proposed tests per device would probably wear down or destroy them even *if* they could be done but it's a good idea.

Answer (score 6):

> However, nothing is being done about it at this repo which I think is very irresponsible.

Because the "issue" that you're reporting is essentially "users can change the audio volume". That's not a vulnerability (outside of a few very specific threat models), it's an *essential feature*.

And as others have said (both here and in that ticket), PulseAudio has no idea if it's outputting to a pair of 2.5W desktop speakers or an 80,000W stack of concert speakers - so any kind of arbitrary cap like "20%" is useless.

> Which measures, other than building in some mitigation in the pulseaudio code, could be done to prevent exploits of this from actually occurring in the wild (it seems unknown if they already have)?

In order cause harm to someone using this issue you need three conditions:

- The ability to control the output volume from the computer.
- An audio output device (speaker, headphones, etc) that is sufficiently powerful to cause physical damage to someone's hearing.
- The victim to be close enough to the output device that their hearing is damaged.

If we're not talking about preventing the attacker gaining access or putting mitigations in Pulseaudio (which are problematic, as that issue you linked to talks about), then your prevention should focus on the other two points.

From an individual level, that would include things like:

- Using hardware controls to lower the volume of audio devices (e.g, keeping the PulseAudio volume at 100% and using the volume dial on the speaker to lower it to a reasonable level).
- Using lower power output devices that can't cause physical damage.
- Placing a hardware device between PulseAudio and the speakers/headphones that limits the maximum volume.
- Keeping a reasonable distance between yourself and the output devices.
- Avoiding the use in headphones.

At a broader or legislative level, it could include things like:

- Restricting access to higher-powered speakers.
- Banning headphones (especially in-ear ones) that can produce volumes high enough to cause immediate hearing damage.

Comment: ►1. You assume the only measure is a code change and even more a specific one which is a misunderstanding of what I proposed. I never said the volume should be limited, I said limiting the **pace of volume change** would be one way of addressing this.►2. Furthermore, this question is about other measures, not my proposed code change.►3. The three conditions are often met, the latter two probably in estimated half of all case (but nobody tested this).►4. These are great useful points but more specific info **how** would be good.A problem with these is that they're not viable for most vulnerable

Comment: @mYnDstrEAm who are the "most vulnerable", and why are none of those suggestions viable for them? What are you basing that assessment on? And in terms of the "how" that will vary greatly depending on the individual's setup and circumstances, so there aren't really generic answers beyond the very obvious ones. Which points specifically are you unsure how you would implement?

Comment: @mYnDstrEAm limiting the rate of chance of the volume would not solve this issue either, because again, it depends on the hardware after PulseAudio. A 5% increase in the PulseAudio volume could be the difference between comfortable listening and permanent heading damage.

Comment: Those with little computer skills or security protections as well as anybody around such when connected to powerful speakers (many music venues). They're not viable for example because people won't buy extra hardware just to mitigate this issue. There are further reasons such as it being unknown which output devices can or can't cause the problems. How to implement "hardware controls to lower the volume" (listed twice)? No, limiting the max-speed of volume change may not make it impossible but heavily mitigate the risk...cases where the sound is that loud at 2% vol are **rare**.

Comment: @mYnDstrEAm so the "most vulnerable" people are those who are running *PulseAudio on Linux*, but with no computing skills, with an expensive profession-grade audio equipment in a setup where one person adjusting the software volume control would cause permanent hearing damage to people, but no hardware between PulseAudio and the speakers that allows them to control or limit the volume? That's far too much of an edge case to be able to cover with generic recommendations, and PulseAudio is the last of their problems in that case. Have you ever encountered this, and can you describe their setup?

Comment: @mYnDstrEAm but you don't need special hardware or skills to be protected against this. My laptop is safe, because the cheap little speakers in it can't do any damage. My desktop is safe because both my headphones and speakers have physical volume controls on. So without any cost, special knowledge or even thought about this "vulnerability" I'm protected against it. 2/2

Comment: I should have said those are among the most vulnerable people, other vulnerable people are people in for example regions of conflict (or otherwise targeted) or those living together with other people who do "pranks" and things of that sort. I didn't say no computing skills, just not beyond average skills or rather IT security measures. Why do you think "expensive profession-grade audio equipment" would be required? It isn't & even IF it was, many people have access to such for at least a short while or via 2ndhand.I asked how one could limit volume with device between (which nearly noone has).

Comment: Your or other people's ears when using your laptop are not safe since the laptop may be connected to much louder speakers or to headphones. The laptop is not safe since its speakers may get destroyed by this. If your desktop audio environment is safe, then my question is about **how** you made it so - how did you implement physical volume controls that sufficiently mitigate this? You're not protected beyond whatever measures you have to prevent unauthorized access.

Comment: @mYnDstrEAm that's a pretty big claim to make. Can you provide some evidence that there is *anything* you can do in PulseAudio that would cause physical damage to a laptop speakers (lets say a Dell Latitude) or to a person in the same room as them? In terms of my speakers, I didn't "implement" anything - they just have a volume dial on the front of them.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that you *can't* handle this in software.

I have a couple of headsets I use. One has a built in amplifier and noise cancelling; having my volume at 10% is perfectly fine for a audio conference, and I can hear things just fine.

Another headset doesn't, and have rather large drivers. Admittedly I should probably use it with an external amplifier, but it works without one. Cranking up to 100% volume yields OK sound level. With my noise cancelling one it'd be deafening. And with external amplifier, it would depend on the volume setting (gain) of the amplifier.

So in short: limits to physical outputs *can't* be handled in the system software that has no knowledge of the properties of the audio speakers.

In a couple of bluetooth headsets I have, the software running in the headsets do perform peak volume shaving; they can do it, because the software is written for a specific headset, containing a specific speaker element. PulseAudio *can't*.

Comment: Of course you could handle it in software, if you wanted to, for example by defining some presets for every device or scenario. The real question is: is it worth it? And without defining a specific threat model first, it looks like any mitigation is not worth it at all.

Comment: Again a misunderstanding: you assume the only measure is a code change and even more a specific one which is a misunderstanding of what I proposed. I never said the volume should be limited, in the issue I proposed limiting the pace of volume change would be one way of addressing this regardless of device. That is one way how it could be handled in software (and that doesn't have to be pulseaudio but could also be GNU/Linux/Debian for example). This question is mainly about other measures, not my proposed code change.

Comment: So you prepare binaries that refuse change quicker than a certain slope/pace - an attacker with access can replace said binary with one without that code path. It ***can't*** be solved in software against an attacker with access to the system. Solving security when you assume an attacker has control over the device is at best difficult.